# How to get specific data from MySql database of an object (like JSONObject type)?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Sorry for my English!
I want to get a specific data of a MySql database and use it in Java (Android) code for doing some tasks.
e.g:
I want to get a Perfil of a person and with it charge an activity depending of the Perfil. I use PHP to get data like JSONObject.

I use the following code

```
public void ObtDatos(){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = DIRECCION + "getDataDetalle.php";

    //Paso parametros, en el caso de los pedidos va que le traiga solo lo
    // que esta asociado al DNI de la persona que esta logueada

    RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
    parametros.put("id",p.getId());

    client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200){
                CargarLista(obtDatosJSON(new String(responseBody)));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}

public void CargarLista(final ArrayList<Comida> datos){
    idPedido.setText(""+p.getId());
    nroPedido.setText("Nº DE PEDIDO: "+p.getId());
    barrio.setText("BARRIO: "+p.getBarrio());
    calle.setText("CALLE: "+p.getDireccion());
    pisoDepto.setText("PISO Y DEPTO: "+p.getPisoDepto());
    String ped ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size();i++){
        ped += datos.get(i).getCantidad() + " " + datos.get(i).getTipo() + " " + datos.get(i).getComida() + " $" +
                Integer.parseInt(datos.get(i).getPrecio())* Integer.parseInt((datos.get(i).getCantidad())) + "\n";
    }
    cantidad.setText("" + ped);
    float monto = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < datos.size();i++){
        monto += Integer.parseInt(datos.get(i).getPrecio())* Integer.parseInt((datos.get(i).getCantidad()));
    }
    montoACobrar.setText("MONTO A COBRAR: " + monto);
    montoPaga.setText("PAGA CON: " + p.getPagaCon());
    float vuelt = Integer.parseInt(p.getPagaCon())-monto;
    vuelto.setText("VUELTO: " + vuelt);
    cliente.setText("CLIENTE: " + p.getCliente());
    telefono.setText("TELÉFONO: " + p.getTelefono());
    origen.getText();


}

public ArrayList<Comida> obtDatosJSON(String response){
    ArrayList<Comida> listadoArray = new ArrayList<Comida>();
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        Comida p;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
            p = new Comida(
                    Integer.parseInt( jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")),
                    Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("idPedido")),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipo"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("comida"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cantidad"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("precio")
            );
            listadoArray.add(p);


        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listadoArray;
}
```

With it code I create Objects (It goes perfect), but I want to get one data (Perfil).

Thanks.

Comment: PLease post your json response